# Assume function is real valued

Tags: assumptions

I want to create a function returning subscripted symbols and I want these symbols to be assumed real. How do I do that?

```
ClearAll[Evaluate[Context[]<>"*"]]

d[n_]:=If[OddQ[n],Subscript[d,n],0]

Map[Re[d[#]]&,Range[1,5]]

(* {Re[Subscript[d, 1]],0,Re[Subscript[d, 3]],0,Re[Subscript[d, 5]]} *)
```

Comment: what do you mean by "I want these symbols to be assumed real."?

Comment: @belisarius Re[d[1]] should return d_1

Answer (score 1):

You can create the following set of upvalues for `Subscript`:

```
Subscript/:(Re|Im)[s_Subscript]:=s
```

if you want to clear the new rules run the command

```
UpValues[Subscript] = {}
```

Comment: It should be also complemented with `Subscript /: Im[s_Subscript] := 0`

Comment: @Yrogirg  done!:)

Answer (score 0):

Although @Spawn1701D 's solution seems to be working for simple cases, I couldn't make Mathematica to take `Re` of more bulky expressions. However there is an easy workaround via [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ComplexExpand.html) :

```
ClearAll[Evaluate[Context[] <> "*"]]

d[n_] := If[OddQ[n], Subscript[d, n], 0]

Map[ComplexExpand[Re[d[#]]] &, Range[1, 5]]

(*{Subscript[d, 1], 0, Subscript[d, 3], 0, Subscript[d, 5]}*)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function `createVars` creates a specified number of subscripted variables, adds the appropriate assumptions to `$Assumtpions` and returns the variable list:

```
createVars[name_String, i_Integer] := With[{
   vars = Array[Subscript[ToExpression@name, #] &, i]},
  If[$Assumptions === True,
$Assumptions = {vars \[Element] Reals},
    AppendTo[$Assumptions, vars \[Element] Reals]];
  vars]
```

To make use of the assumptions, just apply `Simplify`:

[image]

If you want to remove the assumptions at some point, use `$Assumptions=.`.